# How does compiler choose between template specializations featuring an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, tr1

I just came across std::tr1::extent template and it puzzled me. I never ever dealt with array type parameters in my life so I don't understand how they work. So, given the code from gcc `type_traits`

```
template<typename _Tp, unsigned _Uint, std::size_t _Size>
     struct extent<_Tp[_Size], _Uint>

template<typename _Tp, unsigned _Uint>
     struct extent<_Tp[], _Uint>
```

how does compiler chooses between those specializations? What type I should pass to `extent` to get it choose the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
extent<int[], 0>::value == 0 // second one chosen
```

`int[]` is an incomplete type, the compiler doesn't know its `sizeof` value. The outermost dimension may stay incomplete, because it's not important for the array to function correctly in most contexts (in particular, indexing will still work). Something like `int[1][]` wouldn't be a correct type anymore.

```
extent<int[2], 0>::value == 2 // first one chosen
```

Sure this can be nested:

```
extent<int[][2], 0>::value == 0 // second one chosen, with `_Tp` being `int[2]`
extent<int[][2], 1>::value == 2 // second one chosen again
```

Comment: So the second one will be chosen any time there's empty square brackets ([]) in the declaration?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's because `T[]` doesn't match `T[N]`.

Comment: Hm, looks like despite the logic, when `extent<_Tp[_Size], _UInt>` matches against `extent<int[1][2]>`, `_Tp` gets `int[2]` not `int[1]`. But `(int [1])[2]` seems to be so more intuitive...

Comment: You have to consider it as an "array of _Size _Tp", not as a pure textual replacement. The actual rule is more complicated. The rule is that in `T d;` if `d` is `d1[N]`, and the type of `T d1;` is `X T`, then `d` has type `X array of N T`. Apply it for `int i[1];`: `d` is `d1[1]`, and type of `int i;` is "int" (X is empty, `T` is int), `d` has type `array of 1 int`. And applying for `int i[1][2];`: `d` is `d1[2]`. Type of `int i[1];` was `array of 1 int` so `X` is `array of 1`. Overall type is `X array of 2 int` = `array of 1 array of 2 int`.